# ¿Se puede limitar el envío masivo de formulario por AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

He estado trabajando con PHP y AJAX y veo que es muy fácil, pero yo quisiera saber cómo puedo hacer para que no se envíe muchas veces dentro de un corto tiempo algunos valores al servidor.

Por ejemplo para editar una subcategoría de productos.

```
nombresubcategoria = document.getElementById('edNombreSubCategoria').value;
idcategoria = document.getElementById('id_categoria').value;
idsubcategoria = document.getElementById('id_subcategoria').value;
arrayDatos = {
  "EdNombreSubCategoria": nombresubcategoria,
  "IdCategoria": idcategoria,
  "IdSubCategoria": idsubcategoria
};
$.ajax({
  url: ajax,
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    arrayEditarSubCategoria: arrayDatos
  },
  beforeSend: function() {
    alertify.mensaje("Procesando...<br>Espere por favor.");
  },
  success: function(respuesta) {
    //console.log(respuesta);
    if (respuesta == "subCategoriaAEditarExistente") {
      alertify.precaucion('Esta subcategoria ya existe o no se ha tomado ningun cambio alguno.');
    } else if (respuesta == "subCategoriaAnadidaEditada") {
      //alertify.exito('Categoria actualizada exitosamente.<br>Click para Actualizar.', 0, function(s) {
      location.reload();
      // });
    } else if (respuesta == "patronInvalido" || respuesta == "errorEditarSubCategoria") {
      alertify.errorred('Ha ocurrido un error en la edicion de la Subcategoria, por favor recargue la pagina e intente nuevamente.', 0, function() {
        location.reload();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Lo que quisiera es que si la persona envía muchas veces la misma petición, éste sea "frenado" o que no pueda enviar datos por un tiempo. O también que si envía una vez la petición, no pueda volver a enviar otra hasta que sea respondida la primera consulta.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que tener en cuenta que la petición AJAX se realiza en JavaScript en el ordenador del cliente, por lo que, aunque pongas algún sistema en JavaScript para evitar el envío masivo de formularios, un usuario con conocimientos de programación podría saltarse esas comprobaciones. Por lo que deberías plantearte hacer una combinación de sistemas tanto en el lado del cliente como del servidor.

**Lado del cliente:**

Un método sencillo sería crear una variable que usarías como semáforo. Ésta indicaría si una petición está en curso para realizar otra hasta que esa haya concluido.

Entonces podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
// al principio de tu código tendrías algo como peticion_en_curso = false;

if (!peticion_en_curso) {

    peticion_en_curso = true;

    nombresubcategoria = document.getElementById('edNombreSubCategoria').value;
    idcategoria = document.getElementById('id_categoria').value;
    idsubcategoria = document.getElementById('id_subcategoria').value;
    arrayDatos = {
      "EdNombreSubCategoria": nombresubcategoria,
      "IdCategoria": idcategoria,
      "IdSubCategoria": idsubcategoria
    };

    $.ajax({
      url: ajax,
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        arrayEditarSubCategoria: arrayDatos
      },
      beforeSend: function() {
        alertify.mensaje("Procesando...<br>Espere por favor.");
      },
      success: function(respuesta) {
        //console.log(respuesta);
        if (respuesta == "subCategoriaAEditarExistente") {
          alertify.precaucion('Esta subcategoria ya existe o no se ha tomado ningun cambio alguno.');
        } else if (respuesta == "subCategoriaAnadidaEditada") {
          //alertify.exito('Categoria actualizada exitosamente.<br>Click para Actualizar.', 0, function(s) {
          location.reload();
          // });
        } else if (respuesta == "patronInvalido" || respuesta == "errorEditarSubCategoria") {
          alertify.errorred('Ha ocurrido un error en la edicion de la Subcategoria, por favor recargue la pagina e intente nuevamente.', 0, function() {
            location.reload();
          });
        }

        peticion_en_curso = false;
      }
    });
}
```

Pero este sistema es demasiado simple, más como ejemplo que otra cosa porque podría tener problemas. Por ejemplo, si la conexión falla por cualquier motivo, deberías tener un sistema para reenviar la petición si no recibes nada (y tu sistema debería ser idempotencial, es decir, que aunque realices la misma acción varias veces, el resultado será el mismo).

Con el código anterior limitas las peticiones a 1 (porque se usa un valor booleano), pero podrías hacer que sea una variable numérica (inicializada a 0) y hacerle un +1 cuando se haga una petición y un -1 cuando se complete. Entonces en lugar de comparar si es verdadero/falso, comprobarías que fuera menor que tu número máximo de peticiones.

**Lado del servidor:**

Como decía antes, las comprobaciones deberían ir por ambos lados para evitar que usuarios con conocimientos puedan aprovecharse y abusar del sistema. Así que tendrías que hacer algo parecido en el servidor (en este caso, en PHP como indicabas).

Una posibilidad sería, en el servidor crear una sesión y guardar en una variable de sesión el número de peticiones en curso:

- +1 cuando llegue una petición
- Comprobar si hay más de X peticiones y realizar acción X si las hay.
- -1 cuando se despache una petición

El tipo de acción influiría en cómo tratar el lado del cliente. Por ejemplo, podrías devolver un mensaje de error simple; o si usas JSON, devolver un objeto con información sobre por qué se canceló la operación.

Algo como esto al principio de tu código (ojo, no lo he probado y puede contener errores):

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["peticiones_en_curso"])) {
    $_SESSION["peticiones_en_curso"] = 1;
} else {
    $_SESSION["peticiones_en_curso"]++;
}

if ($_SESSION["peticiones_en_curso"] < MAXIMO_NUMERO_PETICIONES) {

    ... tu código ...


    $_SESSION["peticiones_en_curso"]--;

}
```

Comment: ¿Pero y si el codigo de Javascript está en un archivo aparte y no dentro del mismo archivo html/php?
verás, tengo una funcion onclick llamada editarSubCategoria(){} en el archivo javascript pero que obviamente  es ejecutado en el archivo html/php en un <button> 
<Button onclick="editarSubCategoria();">Editar</button> 
¿en que parte usaría la $_SESSION['peticion en curso']?